# Upwork/Odesk API desktop application development

Tags: c#, oauth, odesk, upwork-api

I'm develop application that should use Upwork API (Winforms + C#). 
To have access to Upwork data, need to authorize there. But in https://developers.upwork.com I don't see how can I login via web request/desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use upwork api, there are more requirements:

- Obtain api key https://www.upwork.com/services/api/apply
- Obtain token
- Api key need to be authorized to access the specific resource

For authentication by default probably you will use OAuth1 so when your apiKey was enabled, to request your token you will have to follow [this](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#authentication_oauth-10) steps

Comment: I have api keys (customerKey and customerSecret). But after I need login to upwork via api

Comment: As mentioned above, Upwork is using standard OAuth1.0 so you need to use any http library which will allows you to perform HTTP requests and follow the OAuth1.0 standard in your code. You can find here more details about the OAuth1.0 flow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzZpgSHdKfU . Similar steps you will have to follow using steps described here https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#authentication_oauth-10